# Update image file from parallel Task issue

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, image

I use this code to populate WPF Image Control.

```
string pathToImage = System.IO.Path.Combine(Settings.ContentFolderPath, file);

Image image = new Image();
BitmapImage src = new BitmapImage();
src.BeginInit();
src.UriSource = new Uri(pathToImage, UriKind.Absolute);
src.EndInit();
double ratio = src.Width / src.Height;
image.Source = src;
image.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
image.Height = marquee1.Height;
image.Width = marquee1.Height * ratio;
lstItems.Items.Add(image);
```

Also I have some parallel `Task` **to update this image file.**

But when I try to delete it I am getting the error:  ***File is busy by other process you cannot delete this file.***

How to resolve this issue?

Thank you!

---

UPDATES

So thank you all of you!

The final solution needs to implement

```
src.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
src.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache;
```

the working code looks like

```
Image image = new Image();

BitmapImage src = new BitmapImage();
src.BeginInit();
src.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
src.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache;
src.UriSource = new Uri(pathToImage, UriKind.Absolute);
src.EndInit();
double ratio = src.Width / src.Height;

image.Source = src;
image.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
image.Height = marquee1.Height;
image.Width = marquee1.Height * ratio;
lstItems.Items.Add(image);
result = image.Width;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[MSND BitmapImage.CacheOption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.cacheoption.aspx) says:

> Set the CacheOption to BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad if you wish to close a
>   stream used to create the BitmapImage.

Set the `BitmapImage.CacheOption` to `OnLoad`:

```
BitmapImage src = new BitmapImage();
src.BeginInit();
src.UriSource = new Uri(pathToImage, UriKind.Absolute);
src.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
src.EndInit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the [CacheOption property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.cacheoption.aspx) of the BitmapImage to [BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapcacheoption.aspx).  This will cause it to load the image into memory and close the original file, which should allow you to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

> Also I have some parallel Task to update this image file ... when I try to delete it I am getting the error

In general, you can't delete a Windows file while a process is using it.  The consumer Windows FAQs include [this page](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Why-cant-I-delete-a-file-or-folder) to describe this restriction.  And as [MSDN describes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete.aspx), `File.Delete` will refuse to delete a file that's in use.

Comment: Just as a note, you could open a file with `FILE_SHARE_DELETE`/`FileShare.Delete` and be able to use `File.Delete()` on it, but WPF does not use that mode when opening images.